# Custom UITableViewCell not Showing Reorder Control

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableViewCell that is a subclass of [CEWendell's SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell), a type of cell that allows for custom buttons accessible by horizontal swipe. The problem is that even with `tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:` and `tableView:canMoveRowAtIndexPath:` implemented, as well as explicitly having `[cell setShowsReorderControl:true]`, the reorder control does not show up when editing begins.

I have also tested this with a regular UITableViewCell with the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a somewhat foolish mistake. Since I was using a `UIViewController` subclass, not a `UITableViewController` subclass, I needed to set `[self.tableView setEditing:!self.tableView.editing animated:true]`, not `[self setEditing:!self.editing animated:true]` in order for the tableview to begin editing.